# Monitors to use with Rpi?

Tags: screen

Me again.

Interested in Edge 10 EF185a LED LCD 18.5" DVI Monitor

Notice some monitors are sold as having DVI input, some with DVI-D input. Are these the same and both suitable for use with Rpi?

If they are different, is there a DVI to HDMI cable and a DVI-D to HDMI cable?

Google didn't help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll need is a HDMI to DVI cable, they are pretty cheap and work really well. The different terms mean DVI-D (digital only), DVI-A (analog only), or DVI-I (digital and analog).

But essentially it will work with the RPI. They are not the same, but for Raspberry Pi purposes they are (almost) the same.

[Wikipedia link on DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface)